# Google App Script executing all script files when runnig an action in a Card

Tags: google-apps-script, card

I noticed a strange thing while working on a Gmail addon.

Every time an action is performed from a card (e.g. from a TextButton), the code of all the scripts in the project is executed.

For example, if I add to the project a script that contains only this line:

```
Logger.log("TEST LOG")
```

this line get executed... I can see "TEST LOG" in the excution log.

This is contrary to what I would expect - that only the function set with setFunctionName() for that action is executed.

Is this intended behavior? Can it be avoided?

Does it happen only in development mode or in production mode too (e.g. published project on the Marketplace)?

Comment: That is typical behavior for apps script.  All global variables  get reinitialized and all global functions are called on every function execution.

Comment: What do you mean, in this example you see that everything outside a function get called https://ibb.co/NrpPrbD

Answer (score 0):

#### This is the intended behavior when using Apps Script.

When running any function, all the instructions/variables from all the other files which are outside of functions are being executed as well. This has nothing to do with the script type as this is how Apps Script handles executions.

A way to manage this is to organize all your code in function blocks.